# USD and Gold price correlation

Tags: currency, commodity

[Gold Prices and U.S. Dollar Correlation - 10 Year Chart](https://www.macrotrends.net/1335/dollar-vs-gold-comparison-last-ten-years) shows the similar trend for USD and Gold price for the last 5 years.

Are there known explanations for the correlation?

[image]

Comment: Charts where two time series are plotted on completely different scales (80-125 on the left, 400-2000 on the right) can be somewhat misleading. They make the series look more similar than they are.

Comment: Agree with @noob2. Furthermore, just looking at the chart looks to me more like there is very little relationship. One goes up, the other down, many times. Other times it does not. It is just a chart of closing prices. Very difficult to say anything about correlation that way; apart from it appearing to be very different depending on the time frame (subperiods) you look at.

Comment: Most likely spurious. Try 10y TIPS yield (net chg) vs Gold (% chg) over say 10 or 15 years. The dual axis level chart would suggest a high correlation however, once calculated, you only get an R ~ 0.3.